# Writing a struct's fields and values of different types to a file in Go

Tags: go, struct

I'm writing a simple program that takes in input from a form, populates an instance of a struct with the received data and the writes this received data to a file.

I'm a bit stuck at the moment with figuring out the best way to iterate over the populated struct and write its contents to the file.

The struct in question contains 3 different types of fields (ints, strings, []strings).

I can iterate over them but I am unable to get their actual type.

Inspecting my posted code below with print statements reveals that each of their types is coming back as structs rather than the aforementioned string, int etc.

The desired output format is be plain text.

For example:

```
field_1="value_1"
field_2=10
field_3=["a", "b", "c"]
```

Anyone have any ideas? Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way entirely?

```
func (c *Config) writeConfigToFile(file *os.File) {

    listVal := reflect.ValueOf(c)
    element := listVal.Elem()

    for i := 0; i < element.NumField(); i++ {
        field := element.Field(i)
        myType := reflect.TypeOf(field)

        if myType.Kind() == reflect.Int {
            file.Write(field.Bytes())
            } else {
                file.WriteString(field.String())
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: `reflect.Value.Bytes` does not return what you think it returns. See here https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Bytes

Comment: What format do you want the resulting file to be? JSON, XML, or plain text? If plain text how do you want the data to be formatted? Everything on one line? Or one line per field? And how would the slice be formatted?

Comment: Just to expand on my first comment, if your field is of type `int` calling `Bytes` on its `reflect.Value` will panic because the `Bytes` method works only on values that are of type `[]byte`. Here's an example https://play.golang.org/p/g4UWNhbbzM

Comment: @mkopriva The format will be plain text - I've edited the question to include more details on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `Bytes` method on `reflect.Value` which does not work as you initially intended, you can use either the `strconv` package or the `fmt` to format you fields.

Here's an example using `fmt`:

```
var s string
switch fi.Kind() {
case reflect.String:
    s = fmt.Sprintf("%q", fi.String())
case reflect.Int:
    s = fmt.Sprintf("%d", fi.Int())
case reflect.Slice:
    if fi.Type().Elem().Kind() != reflect.String {
        continue
    }

    s = "["
    for j := 0; j < fi.Len(); j++ {
        s = fmt.Sprintf("%s%q, ", s, fi.Index(i).String()) 
    }
    s = strings.TrimRight(s, ", ") + "]"
default:
    continue
}

sf := rv.Type().Field(i)
if _, err := fmt.Fprintf(file, "%s=%s\n", sf.Name, s); err!= nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/KQF3CicVzA

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [built-in `gob` package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) to store your struct values?

I use it to store different structures, one per line, in files.  During decoding, you can test the type conversion or provide a hint in a wrapper - whichever is faster for your given use case.

You'd treat each line as a buffer when Encoding and Decoding when reading back the line. You can even gzip/zlib/compress, encrypt/decrypt, etc the stream in real-time.

No point in re-inventing the wheel when you have a polished and armorall'd wheel already at your disposal.